# OWA: Dialog API support

Tags: office-js

We use a dialog in our Outlook add-in for authentication. We have logic in our add-in that first checks for dialog API support, then checks if the add-in is framed - in which case it pops a new window for authentication instead. Recently the dialog API lit up for OWA, and has caused us a couple issues.

We fixed some previous issues relating to the order in which we performed authentication (we use `ADAL.js`) and initializing Office. However, once we were past those, it doesn't appear the dialog can communicate back to the add-in using `Office.context.ui.messageParent`.

Additionally, even though the add-in subscribes to `Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogEventReceived` events, they don't get fired when the dialog is closed (typically closing a dialog returns a `12006` error code, which we guard for).

I created a simple Outlook add-in that solely opens a dialog, and verified that it still can't communicate with the add-in in OWA. I've included the code below.

Add-in code:

```js
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var resultArea = $("span");
        $("button").click(function () {
            resultArea.text("Opening dialog");
            Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync(
                window.location.origin + "/TestAddin/Dialog.html",
                { height: 75, width: 25 },
                function (asyncResult) {
                    if (asyncResult.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
                        var dialog = asyncResult.value;
                        dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, function handleAuthDialogMessage(message) {
                            dialog.close();
                            resultArea.text(message);
                        });
                        dialog.addEventHandler(Microsoft.Office.WebExtension.EventType.DialogEventReceived, function handleAuthDialogMessage(message) {
                            resultArea.text("Event encountered");
                        });
                    } else {
                        resultArea.text("Dialog failed");
                    }
                });
        });
    })
};
```

Dialog code:

```js
Office.initialize = function (reason) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Office.context.ui.messageParent("dialog-opened");
    })
};
```

For now I've adjusted our add-in to first check to see if it is framed (in which case it opens a new window for authentication) before it checks for or uses the dialog API. This approach allows us to fix our production bug, and re-enable OWA authentication; however, I would like to uptake the dialog once it's working or our add-in is fixed :)

Is anyone aware of this issue already?

--- Update 2/22 ---

It appears that the dialog can now message parents. Unfortunately there's still an outstanding bug where closing the dialog doesn't trigger an event to be sent to the add-in.

Comment: If you can share your manifest pointing to an internet deployed version of your add-in it might be easier to repro.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Could not reproduce the message parent issue.

Regarding DialogEventReceived events not firing when the dialog is closed - this is a known issue that we are working on a fix for already, but thanks for reporting!

Comment: We are getting events on close if the user clicks on the X, but not if the user hits ESC while the focus is on our controls within the dialog. Is that part of the known issue?

Comment: @Igaud check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037829/no-event-is-fired-when-closing-a-dialog-via-esc this is still an issue.