# No event is fired when closing a dialog via ESC

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

This issue is occurring using Outlook Web App on OSX. It has been replicated  using Chrome, Firefox, and Safari.

**Scenario**

[UI.displayDialogAsync()](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync) is used with the `displayInIframe: true` option.

If a user hits the ESC key, the dialog will close but not trigger `Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived`.

On top of this, the same dialog can not be opened again (probably because somewhere an opened flag is still set to true or something).

---

**Expected Behavior**

The dialog closes and emits an event with error `12006` (dialog closed by user).

---

**Current Behavior**

The dialog closes, and does not emit anything and dialog cannot be reopened.

---

**Code**

All our OfficeJs related calls are wrapped inside a service, and inside that service we have an `openDialog` method that wraps `ui.displayDialogAsync`:

```ts
public openDialog(dialog: string, width: number, height: number, displayInIframe: boolean = true) : Promise < Office.DialogHandler > {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.ui.displayDialogAsync(`https://${OWA_HOST}/${dialog}`, { width, height, displayInIframe }, (result) => {
            //... error handling + reject(result.value)
            resolve(result.value)
        });
    });
}
```

`openDialog` is then used somwhere else in our Angular app:

```ts
this.owaService.openDialog('dialog-access-rights.html', 60, 50, true)
    .then((handler: Office.DialogHandler) => {
        this.handler = handler;
        handler.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, this.messageHandler.bind(this));
        handler.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogEventReceived, this.eventHandler.bind(this));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        this.log.error('Error opening AR dialog', {
            error
        });
    });
```

*error returned by Office :*

[image]

---

I've posted this in the [Office.js CDN/NPM GitHub](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/9) as well.

This issue: [OWA: Dialog API support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147758/owa-dialog-api-support?rq=1) is similar, though I've left my question as-is since it is a more barebone description of the same bug.

Comment: Is this happening across hosts (Word, PPT, Excel, Outlook, etc) and across platforms (Windows, Mac, Web, iOS, etc)?

Comment: I have no Idea, to be honest. I'm on Mac, and I don't use windows products at all :/ The add-in i'm working on is also in early development so we're not testing on those platforms yet as web is our main target.

Comment: Is this happening across browsers (chrome, firefox, safari) or just desktop? Also, is this happening regardless of host (word, excel, etc)?

Comment: Yes, all three. I don't know if this is happening regardless of host, because I do not have those applications installed, nor do I wish to install them.

Comment: I don't follow. I'm ask if this happens with Word Online, Excel Online, etc.

Comment: It happens in all three major browsers on OSX. I don't know if it happens in other Office 365 webapps, as the add-in I'm working on only has to work for Outlook (for now) and I'm not using nor testing on the other Office 365 webapps.

Comment: One clarification, Office 365 is just a subscription and not the web versions of the Office products. For example, depending on your subscription you could have access to Word Online and/or Word 2016 for Mac. In this case, Outlook is unique in that Outlook Web Access requires either an Outlook.com or Exchange Online mailbox.  I assume you're using this with an O365/Exchange mailbox?

Comment: I assume setting `displayInIframe: false` doesn't result in this issue?

Comment: Regarding the subscription type, yes, this concerns an `O365 E1` license. How exactly is that question relevant if the bug i'm reporting concerns navigation UX / API behaviour ?
Regarding `displayInIframe: false`: this doesn't work at all for me. A new tab opens, instead of a window, which consequently can't locate the HTML file that i'm passing.

Comment: It's relevant in so far as ensuring we are on the same page. Proper terminology also helps future readers, which speaks to the heart of SO's value proposition. As for opening a new tab and an inability to open the correct page, that is unexpected behavior. Could you add the actual call your making to the question? I suspect these behaviors may be related.

Comment: but we `are` on the [same page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037829/no-event-is-fired-when-closing-a-dialog-via-esc#comment79153825_46037829)! joking aside, I was only partly correct. setting `displayInIframe: false` does open the correct page, but indeed not in a small window but in a new tab.

I've added the actuall call to the question.

Comment: I see I forgot to add the error Office returns as well, I've added it now.

Comment: I also experience the bug without focusing on an element on the page, just hitting ESC is enough to reproduce.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT Could you give an update? i.e., is this added to an internal OfficeJs bug tracker, is it being investigated etc. etc.

Comment: Thanks for reporting a bug in our API. We've added it to the backlog to fix this ASAP.

Thanks again,
Outlook Engineering Team

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT any indication what version, or when this will be fixed? It's really hard for developers using officeJs to have *any* view on this as you do not have a public bugtracker, nor roadmap, nor...nada.